# How to change the language with a button in Android Studio

Tags: android

Please assist,

I have created two addition language resource and would like to give the game the option to change the language option with a button selection.

I created a class called LocaleHelper which I found via google as per below however the locale has since been depricated. How to go about now?

```
    package biz.myecard.mathisfun;

/**
 * Created by Hans Fouche on 2016/10/18.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static void onCreate(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);
        updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

It is the called in the button method with:

```
LocaleHelper.onCreate(this, "en");
```

**Error as below:** My APP works but don't thinks this is optimal.

Note: /Users/macintoshhd/Desktop/AndroidCourse/MathisFun/app/src/main/java/biz/myecard/mathisfun/LocaleHelper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: That's not an error, just a deprecation warning

Comment: Thanks but do you know what the new and correct (optimal) way is?

Comment: It's not clear what method is giving you that warning.

Comment: its the : configuration.**locale** = locale;

Comment: I will prefer to use settings. Using this, User can change his/her preferred language. You can provide list of language and show your content based on this selection using preferenceManager. You can use Java Locale to build custom list on the fly. Do let me know and i will share the code for currency, which i implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read java doc first:

> This field was deprecated in API level 24. Do not set or read this directly. Use getLocales() and setLocales(LocaleList). If only the primary locale is needed, getLocales().get(0) is now the preferred accessor.

So you are able to do so:

```
private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
    } else {
        configuration.locale = locale;
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Deprecation means that method isn't currently supported and could be removed in next versions of api. But in the previous ones you can't avoid using it, because there weren't new methods (setters & getter, which have been provided since 17&21 api)

Comment: Thanks would like to use this however when I add this code in my onCreate just for testing before adding to a button or settings the configuration is not recognized.

Comment: @HansFouche it means, that you should use this snippet in your `updateResources` method. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks, dont want to sound stupid pretty new. I see I need to create a method and call like: updateResources(???, "es") what do I pass in the context. This code would also replace my LocaleHelper class?